# Inserting in SQL Server Table based on Different Table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I had these two tables in sql server database for C# application.

```
----------------------------
table_Items
----------------------------
Item1 | Item2| Item3 | Item4
A     | B    | C     | D
E     | F    | G     | Null
H     | I    | Null  | Null
J     | Null | Null  | Null

------------------
table_Item_Shelves
------------------
Item_Name | Item_ID
A     |  Null
B     |  Null
C     |  Null
D     |  Null
E     |  Null
```

This is what i needed to do.
For each row in table_items, first check if row has values in all(item 1,2,3,4) or three of the fields,
than in table_Item_Shelves insert '1' for each item in Item_ID field. For next row conduct the same check
and get maximum value from Item_ID field and increment by 1. I also need to check that maximum four Item_ID's can be same.
Any help in C# and SQL will be great. Thanks.

If table_Item_Shelves column Item_ID already has a value than i should not insert new ID
table_Item_Shelves already contain records, and i need to update against those records.

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateItemIDs
    AS 
        BEGIN
            SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Item1 ) AS RowIndex ,
                    IT.* ,
                    0 AS processed
            INTO    #TempTable
            FROM    dbo.table_items IT
            WHERE   ( Item1 IS NOT NULL
                      AND Item2 IS NOT NULL
                      AND item3 IS NOT NULL
                    )
                    OR ( Item1 IS NOT NULL
                         AND Item2 IS NOT NULL
                         AND item4 IS NOT NULL
                       )
                    OR ( Item1 IS NOT NULL
                         AND Item3 IS NOT NULL
                         AND item4 IS NOT NULL
                       )
                    OR ( Item2 IS NOT NULL
                         AND Item3 IS NOT NULL
                         AND item4 IS NOT NULL
                       )

```
        DECLARE @ITEM1 VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @ITEM2 VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @ITEM3 VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @ITEM4 VARCHAR(50)
        DECLARE @RowIndex INT
        DECLARE @NewItemID INT

        WHILE ( SELECT  COUNT(*)
                FROM    #TempTable
                WHERE   processed = 0
              ) > 0 
            BEGIN
                SELECT TOP 1
                        @ITEM1 = Item1 ,
                        @ITEM2 = Item2 ,
                        @ITEM3 = item3 ,
                        @ITEM4 = Item4 ,
                        @RowIndex = RowIndex
                FROM    #TempTable
                WHERE   processed = 0

                UPDATE  #TempTable
                SET     processed = 1
                WHERE   RowIndex = @RowIndex

                SET @NewItemID = ( SELECT   ISNULL(MAX(Item_ID), 0) + 1
                                   FROM     dbo.table_items_shelves
                                 ) ;

                UPDATE  dbo.table_items_shelves
                SET     Item_ID = @NewItemID
                WHERE   Item_Name IN ( @ITEM1, @ITEM2, @ITEM3, @ITEM4 )
                        AND Item_ID IS NULL
            END
    END
```

I have this above stored Procedure which works (From the help of someone), but i need to modify it to work with 8 columns in table_items(Item1,Item2.....Item8), and check if row has values in all(item1, item2....item8) or 5 of the fields,
than in table_Item_Shelves insert '1' for each item in Item_ID field.
For 8 columns in in table_items(Item1,Item2.....Item8)

```
    able_Items
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Item1   | Item2    | Item3     | Item4 | Item5 | Item6 | Item7 | Item8 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Pencils |  Rubbers | Books     | DvDs  | Glue  |Stapler| CDs   |Mouse  |
Marker  |KeyChain  |Clipboards |Pens   |Bucket| Null   |
Monitors|  Null    |
Glue  | Null   |Null | Null | Null  | Null | Null   | Null  | Null  |
Papers| Null  | Null | Null



table_Item_Shelves
------------------
Item_Name | Item_ID
-------------------
Pencils   |  Null
Rubbers   |  Null
Pens      |  Null
Books     |  Null
Staplers  |  Null
Glue      |  Null
Buckets   |  Null
Keyborads |  Null
Monitors  |  Null
Mouse     |  Null
CDs       |  Null
DvDs      |  Null
Papers    |  Null
Clipboards|  Null
Markers   |  Null
KeyChains |  Null
```

Now from the Data in tables Provided i expect results something like this

table_Items has values in all columns in row 1,

There is no Item_ID in table so for each item in row 1 i will insert '1' . Than check Row 2, it has 5 items so for each item, i will insert Max(Item_ID) + 1.

Row 3<5  AND Row 4 < 5  AND Row 5<5  columns with values AND ROW 3+ ROW 4 + ROW 5 is also < 5, so i ignore them. also if  "Item_ID" is not "NULL or Empty" i ignore the column.

The end result will look like this.

```
    table_Item_Shelves
------------------
Item_Name | Item_ID
-------------------
Pencils   |  1
Rubbers   |  1
Pens      |  2
Books     |  1
Staplers  |  1
Glue      |  1
Buckets   |  2
Keyborads |  Null
Monitors  |  Null
Mouse     |  1
CDs       |  1
DvDs      |  1
Papers    |  Null
Clipboards|  2
Markers   |  2
KeyChains |  2
```

No Design Suggestions please, i know it is horrible. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably read up on 'data normalization' as this may help you in a more general sense. There seems to be some design flaws (unless I don't understand the more general context of your constraints and application).

Comment: Don't know what your data looks like, but off the top of my head, this is a pretty funky design. I would suggest trying to flip it from one row with up to possibly 8 columns to up to 8 rows with one value each.

Comment: @Andrew i forgot to write this before "No Design Suggestions please, i know it is horrible. Thanks". If i was this smart to implement your idea i wouldn't have been here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work.

```
using System;

    using System.Collections.Generic;

    using System.Data;

    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    using System.Linq;

    using System.Text;


    namespace InsertTeamIdIntoTable

    {

        class Program

        {

            const string str = @"Data Source=(localdb)\Projects;Initial Catalog=TestDb;Integrated Security=SSPI";

            static void Main(string[] args)

            {


                InsertItemData(str);

            }


            private static void InsertItemData(string connectionString)

            {

                string queryString =

                    "SELECT item1,item2,item3,item4 FROM dbo.table_items;";


                using (SqlConnection connection =

                           new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                {

                    SqlCommand command =

                        new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

                    connection.Open();


                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    int itemId = 1;

                    //check if row has values in all(item 1,2,3,4) or three of the fields,

                    while (reader.Read())

                    {

                        bool flag = CheckValueNumber((IDataRecord)reader);

                        if (flag)

                        {


                            for (int i = 0; i < ((IDataRecord)reader).FieldCount; i++)

                            {

                                string itemName = ((IDataRecord)reader)[i].ToString();

                                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemName) == false)

                                {

                                    if (CheckItemShelveExists(str, itemName))

                                    {

                                        if (CheckItemIdExists(str, itemName) == false)

                                        {

                                            UpdateTableItemShelves(str, itemId, itemName);

                                        }

                                    }

                                    else

                                    {

                                        InsertTableItemShelves(str, itemId, itemName);

                                    }

                                }

                            }

                            itemId++;

                        }

                    }

                    reader.Close();

                }

            }


            public static void UpdateTableItemShelves(string connectionString, int itemId, string itemName)

            {

                string updateString = string.Format("Update dbo.table_item_shelves set item_id ={0} WHERE item_name ='{1}';", itemId, itemName);


                using (SqlConnection connection =

                           new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                {

                    SqlCommand command =

                        new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);

                    connection.Open();


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }

            }


            public static void InsertTableItemShelves(string connectionString, int itemId, string itemName)

            {

                string updateString = string.Format("Insert Into dbo.table_item_shelves(item_id,item_name) VALUES({0},'{1}');", itemId, itemName);


                using (SqlConnection connection =

                           new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                {

                    SqlCommand command =

                        new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);

                    connection.Open();


                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();


                }

            }



            public static bool CheckItemShelveExists(string connectionString, string itemName)

            {

                string updateString = string.Format("Select count(id) From dbo.table_item_shelves WHERE item_name ='{0}';", itemName);


                using (SqlConnection connection =

                           new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                {

                    SqlCommand command =

                        new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);

                    connection.Open();


                    return (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar() > 0;


                }

            }


            public static bool CheckItemIdExists(string connectionString, string itemName)

            {

                string updateString = string.Format("Select item_id From dbo.table_item_shelves WHERE item_name ='{0}';", itemName);


                using (SqlConnection connection =

                           new SqlConnection(connectionString))

                {

                    SqlCommand command =

                        new SqlCommand(updateString, connection);

                    connection.Open();

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                    while (reader.Read())

                    {

                        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((IDataRecord)reader)[0].ToString()) == false)

                        {

                            return true;

                        }

                    }


                    reader.Close();

                    return false;


                }

            }


            public static bool CheckValueNumber(IDataRecord record)

            {

                int count = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < record.FieldCount; i++)

                {

                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record[i].ToString()) == false)

                    {

                        count++;

                    }

                }

                return count >= 3;

            }


        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand your desired final outcome (no expected result example) but the first part of your procedures WHERE claus could be simplified dramatically to deal with more fields more easily...

```
-- OLD 
WHERE   ( Item1 IS NOT NULL
              AND Item2 IS NOT NULL
              AND item3 IS NOT NULL
            )
            OR ( Item1 IS NOT NULL
                 AND Item2 IS NOT NULL
                 AND item4 IS NOT NULL
               )
            OR ( Item1 IS NOT NULL
                 AND Item3 IS NOT NULL
                 AND item4 IS NOT NULL
               )
            OR ( Item2 IS NOT NULL
                 AND Item3 IS NOT NULL
                 AND item4 IS NOT NULL
               )
```

by using an alternate format like this (extra data to allow query to run standalone)

This format allows you to just duplicate the CASE statements and change the Criteria on the count of valid fields.

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT 'A' AS Item1, 'B' AS Item2, 'C' AS Item3, 'D' AS Item4
    UNION ALL SELECT 'E', 'F', 'G', NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 'H', 'I', NULL, NULL
    UNION ALL SELECT 'J', NULL, NULL, NULL
), B AS (
    SELECT A.*
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY Item1 ) AS RowIndex
        , 0 AS processed
        , CASE WHEN Item1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
            + CASE WHEN Item2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            + CASE WHEN Item3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            + CASE WHEN Item4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            AS ValidFieldCount
    FROM A
)
SELECT * 
FROM B
WHERE ValidFieldCount >=3
```

Comment: Could also just put the CASE statement in the where clause directly instead of a sub-query.

Comment: Please check if it makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in c#. If i can create arrays for each row and than use those values to update the second table?